# Intellij caching issue - need to rebuild project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I keep running into this issue with Intellij, where when i add a new method to a class, compilation fails saying that it cant find that new method, perhaps because the cache doesn't contain that method signature, although i just added the new method.

I have to rebuild the entire project which takes about an hour..

Is there anything i can do to avoid a rebuild and save that time?

Comment: Try starting IntelliJ as it can get confused. Adding the method should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try `File` | **Invalidate Caches** and restart. If it doesn't help, [contact JetBrains support](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=IDEA) with a sample project and the steps to reproduce.